# Can I use SMTP with Swift Mailer while not defining a username and password

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to use Swift Mailer to send an email to a client on her website. The problem is, I do not know her username/password email information, and I do not want to use mine.

Is there a way to use SMTP with Swift Mailer, and not define a username, password, or email host? Kinda how the mail function will allow you to use anything for the to/from addresses.

Comment: You can certainly send email without an email account.  But, depending on your mail server, it is almost guaranteed to end up in her spam box or even deleted by the receiving server.

Comment: @Chris: But I need a way to send an email, without writing down somebodys email information in the code. Thats the problem I am having. So the only other option I can think of is to go back to the built in mail function, which everyone recommends against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have for one of our scripts and I believe it does exactly that.

```
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  //Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject('Webinar Registration')
  //Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('FROM EMAIL ADDRESS' => 'FROM NAME'))
  //Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array('TO EMAIL ADDRESS'))
  //Give it a body
  ->setBody('My Message')
  //And optionally an alternative body
  //->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')
  ;

//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('127.0.0.1', 25);
//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

This was probably copy-pasted and slightly modified from the Swift mailer documentation. All we're doing is connecting to SMTP on localhost.

**Edit**: Looking at comments on the original post, I do have to wonder about triggering spam filters. We haven't really had a problem with it... one, maybe two users have complained about not receiving e-mails. If there's any good documentation on this kind of stuff and ways to avoid these problems, I'd love to have a link to it. I think we just have the default IIS SMTP server running on our machine as set up by our provider.

**Another Edit**: Ah, if this is going on to someone else's website, we don't know exactly how they're set up. I wonder if you could create an account with some other e-mail provider (assuming it's not against their terms of use.) Maybe I jumped the gun with my post, sorry.

Comment: If the localhost suggestion works, then I am willing to try. I am uploading the code now to try it out. I will get back to you in a second.

Comment: @Metropolis - I'm hoping you got it working. Should seriously take the whole spam filtering issue into consideration though. I'm not an e-mail expert, so that's definitely a question I'd love to see addressed/answered somewhere. (Although looks like a non-issue for you at this point.)

Comment: Well heres the thing about the spam filtering. These emails are going to one person, so if it gets caught by their spam filter then we will know about it right away. If it does not, then theres nothing wrong with it and it will work fine. If I was sending this out to a large amount of people I could see this being a big problem for sure. But until that time comes up, this is working fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this right you **have** to use a real email address and send it from a server that is properly configured.  Otherwise your mail **will** end up in their spam box.

Just have your client set up an email address called support@whateverthedomainis.com  which would be for this.  If for whatever silly reason they can't do that then set up a mail address at gmail or some other free email provider and send it through their mail server.

There is a LOT that goes into properly configuring a mail server in todays world.  From blacklist management, reverse dns configuration, SPF setup, etc.  Point is providers are getting more finicky every day and if you want to see your application work long term then you'll need to do this right.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Heres the thing though....I am only sending it to the client, and I am likely to test it before putting it into production. So I can technically do it without using a username/password every time until I run across a client that it goes into their spam box. If I run into a client where the email is going into the spam box, then I will alter it for them. Otherwise what is it hurting?

Comment: @Metropolis: The problem is that it is highly likely that at some point it is going to fail.  Isn't it better to do it right to begin with so you don't have to worry about it?

Comment: It just makes no sense to me that there has to be authentication data just to use it. I do not want to have to ask every single client to give me an email address to use, and I do not want to use one of my own.